# "Missing return statement" error in Java

Tags: java, constructor, return

I don't know what's wrong with this one. I have done this with examples of other codes. And now I'm stuck just because of this single thing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Praktikum3
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

String NIP, nama, kelamin, jabat, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4;
int a, b, c, d, e, umur, menjabat, tgllhr, blnlhr, thnlhr, lhr, blnjbt, thnjbt, date, month, year;

public Praktikum3() //constructor
{
    System.out.printf("DATA KARYAWAN\n\n"); //menginisialkan constructor
}

public void setNama()
{
    System.out.printf("Nama: " );
    nama = scan.next();
}

public String getNama()
{
    return nama;
}

public void setNIP()
{
    System.out.printf("NIP : " );
    while (!scan.hasNextLong())
    {
        System.out.printf("!HARUS ANGKA!\n");
        System.out.printf("NIP : ");
        scan.next();
    }
    NIP = scan.next();

    if(NIP.length() != 18)
    {
        System.out.printf("!HARUS 18 KARAKTER!\n");
        System.out.printf("NIP : ");
        scan.next();
    }

    sub1 = NIP.substring(0,8); /*substring Tanggal lahir*/
    sub2 = NIP.substring(8,14); /*substring Masa menjabat*/
    sub3 = NIP.substring(14,15); /*substring Jenis kelamin*/
    sub4 = NIP.substring(15,18); /*substring Nomor urut*/

    date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    a = Integer.parseInt(sub1.substring(6,8));
    b = Integer.parseInt(sub1.substring(4,6));
    c = Integer.parseInt(sub1.substring(0,4));

    d = Integer.parseInt(sub2.substring(4,6));
    e = Integer.parseInt(sub2.substring(0,4));
}

public String getSub1()
{
    return sub1;
}

public String getSub2()
{
    return sub2;
}

public String getSub3()
{
    return sub3;
}

public String getSub4()
{
    return sub4;
}

public int getTgllhr()
{
    return a;
}

public int getBlnlhr()
{
    return b;
}

public int getThnlhr()
{
    return c;
}

public int getUmur()
{
    tgllhr = date - a;

    blnlhr = month - b;
    if(blnlhr < 0)
        lhr = -1;
    else if(tgllhr < 0)
        lhr = -1;
    else
        lhr = 0;

    thnlhr = year - c;

    umur = thnlhr + lhr;

    return umur;
}

public String getKelamin()
{
    if(sub3.equals("1"))
        kelamin = "Pria";
    else if(sub3.equals("2"))
        kelamin = "Wanita";
    else
        kelamin = "Ganda";
}

public int getMenjabat()
{
    blnjbt = month - d;
    if(blnjbt < 0)
        blnjbt = -1;
    else
        blnjbt = 0;

    thnjbt = year - e;

    menjabat = thnjbt + blnlhr;

    return menjabat;
}

public static void main(String[]arbi)
{
    Praktikum3 dt = new Praktikum3();

    dt.setNama();
    dt.setNIP();

    System.out.printf("\nData\n----\n");
    System.out.printf("Nama          : %s\n", dt.getNama());
    //System.out.printf("NIP           : %s.%s.%s.%s\n", dt.getSub1, dt.getSub2, dt.getSub3, dt.getSub4);
    //System.out.printf("Tanggal lahir : %d-%d-%d\n", dt.getTgllhr, dt.getBlnlhr, dt.getThnlhr);
    System.out.printf("Umur          : %d tahun\n", dt.getUmur());
    System.out.printf("Jenis kelamin : %s\n", dt.getKelamin());
    System.out.printf("Lama menjabat : %d tahun", dt.getMenjabat());
}
}
```

This one is in Indonesian. This one I used to practice substring with OOP. Even the get substring method were error.

Error message:

> Praktikum3.java:125: error: missing return statement }

Comment: What is your actual and complete error message? Which line of code is involved?

Comment: Chit, your title is completely misleading as your question has nothing to do with a constructor problem. Next time, please put a little more effort into asking a complete and accurate question.

Comment: Arbintoro, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, your function names are in Indonesian, please explain them with code comments, as they are not in english

Comment: variables like `int a, b, c, d, e,` are next to useless.  If you were to look at this code in 3 months time would you remember what they meant?

Comment: Okay understood. First time asking on stackoverflow. Will be better next time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed the `return statement` for this method.you should return a `String` because `return type is string` in this method.and `"Constructor Missing Return Statement"` is meaningless because `constructors haven't a return type`

```
public String getKelamin()
{
    if(sub3.equals("1"))
        kelamin = "Pria";
    else if(sub3.equals("2"))
        kelamin = "Wanita";
    else
        kelamin = "Ganda";
    return kelamin;
}
```

Comment: This is the errormessage

Praktikum3.java:125: error: missing return statement
        }

Now it's working fine with the constructor. Thanks :)

Comment: @ArbintoroMas it saying that you don't return a String from this method.so you need to return a string .i hope that problem is fixed.i think you are newbie for java.good luck u

Comment: Yes sir, I just got started on Java programming. Thanks for the help, even though it's just my little mistake. Learned new error problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Final Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Praktikum3
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

String NIP, nama, kelamin, jabat, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4;
int a, b, c, d, e, umur, menjabat, tgllhr, blnlhr, thnlhr, lhr, blnjbt, thnjbt, date, month, year;

public Praktikum3() //constructor
{
    System.out.printf("DATA KARYAWAN\n\n"); //menginisialkan constructor
}

public void setNama()
{
    System.out.printf("Nama: " );
    nama = scan.next();
}

public String getNama()
{
    return nama;
}

public void setNIP()
{
    System.out.printf("NIP : " );

    while (!scan.hasNextLong())
    {
        System.out.printf("!HARUS ANGKA!\n");
        System.out.printf("NIP : ");
        scan.next();
    }
    NIP = scan.next();

    if(NIP.length() != 18)
    {
        System.out.printf("!HARUS 18 KARAKTER!\n");
        System.out.printf("NIP : ");
        NIP = scan.next();
    }

    sub1 = NIP.substring(0,8); /*substring Tanggal lahir*/
    sub2 = NIP.substring(8,14); /*substring Masa menjabat*/
    sub3 = NIP.substring(14,15); /*substring Jenis kelamin*/
    sub4 = NIP.substring(15,18); /*substring Nomor urut*/

    date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    a = Integer.parseInt(sub1.substring(6,8));
    b = Integer.parseInt(sub1.substring(4,6));
    c = Integer.parseInt(sub1.substring(0,4));

    d = Integer.parseInt(sub2.substring(4,6));
    e = Integer.parseInt(sub2.substring(0,4));
}

public String getSub1()
{
    return sub1;
}

public String getSub2()
{
    return sub2;
}

public String getSub3()
{
    return sub3;
}

public String getSub4()
{
    return sub4;
}

public int getTgllhr()
{
    return a;
}

public int getBlnlhr()
{
    return b;
}

public int getThnlhr()
{       
    return c;
}

public int getUmur()
{
    tgllhr = date - a;

    blnlhr = month - b;
    if(blnlhr < 0)
        lhr = -1;
    else if(tgllhr < 0)
        lhr = -1;
    else
        lhr = 0;

    thnlhr = year - c;

    umur = thnlhr + lhr;

    return umur;
}

public String getKelamin()
{
    if(sub3.equals("1"))
        kelamin = "Pria";
    else if(sub3.equals("2"))
        kelamin = "Wanita";
    else
        kelamin = "Ganda";

    return kelamin;
}

public int getMenjabat()
{
    blnjbt = month - d;
    if(blnjbt < 0)
        blnjbt = -1;
    else
        blnjbt = 0;

    thnjbt = year - e;

    menjabat = thnjbt + blnlhr;

    return menjabat;
}

public static void main(String[]arbi)
{
    Praktikum3 dt = new Praktikum3();

    dt.setNama();
    dt.setNIP();

    System.out.printf("\nData\n----\n");
    System.out.printf("Nama          : %s\n", dt.getNama());
    System.out.printf("NIP           : %s.%s.%s.%s\n", dt.getSub1(), dt.getSub2(), dt.getSub3(), dt.getSub4());
    System.out.printf("Tanggal lahir : %d-%d-%d\n", dt.getTgllhr(), dt.getBlnlhr(), dt.getThnlhr());
    System.out.printf("Umur          : %d tahun\n", dt.getUmur());
    System.out.printf("Jenis kelamin : %s\n", dt.getKelamin());
    System.out.printf("Lama menjabat : %d tahun", dt.getMenjabat());
}
}
```